# Get object back from ListView

Tags: c#, listview, uwp

I have a XAML ListView that has it's data bound to it with an object simply like this:

```
ThisList.ItemsSource = folderItem;
```

So I would have thought to get that data back out all I would have to do is:-

```
folderItem = ThisList.ItemsSource;
```

But I get an error saying "Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)".

But if I cast with a

```
(FolderInfo)
```

it objects to that with an error. If I cast with a

```
(ObservableCollection<FolderInfo>)
```

It compiles but the folderItem always returns with a null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the code when you do `(ObservableCollection<FolderInfo>)ThisList.ItemsSource`? If it's *null*, then maybe you are trying to access *ItemsSource* before it's assigned?

Comment: ItemsSource is Ilist

Comment: Romasz - The list view is fully populated before, as I'm only trying to pull the ItemSource back after it's fully populated, by reacting to a tapped event.

Comment: Lindexi - I don't understand your point?

Comment: use ThisList.Items; instead of ThisList.ItemsSource;

Comment: I get errors with all of these:-             thisFolderItem = (ObservableCollection<FolderInfo>)ThisList.Items[] ;
            thisFolderItem = (ObservableCollection<FolderInfo>)ThisList.Items;
            thisFolderItem = ThisList.Items;

Comment: I guess I just have to iterate through ThisList.Items[x] one by one and repopulate the object.